# javascript add operation returns bad result

Tags: javascript, addition

I've a funny idiotic problem: 
Why is `javascript` showing that `10.2 - 17 = -6.800000000000001` ?

Found something similar here: [Calculate a minus operation in javascript returns a incorrect value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966867/calculate-a-minus-operation-in-javascript-returns-a-incorrect-value) but I can't round the numbers.

Can I somehow fix this without specifying how many decimals to use? (I actually have some results that can have 6-7 decimals)

Comment: This might be helpful http://blog.thatscaptaintoyou.com/introducing-big-js-arbitrary-precision-math-for-javascript/

Comment: Duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken) (and [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem?lq=1)s). There are some libraries around that can help, e.g., [BigDecimal](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) and [BigNumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is not always precise.

In particular there is no exact representation of 10.2 as a floating point value, so the nearest representable value is stored instead. This value will be very slightly different from 10.2.

The simplest way to handle it is to round the numbers to a certain number of decimal places when you display them.

Some languages have a `decimal` type that can represent 10.2 exactly. However:

- Javascript has no built in type like this, so you'd have to use a third-party library.
- Decimal floating point numbers don't solve all problems. For example the result of `0.1 / 0.3` cannot be represented exactly as a decimal. You may still need to round results to a certain number of decimal places when you display them.

Comment: So unfortunately I need to make a check before doing the operation to see the number of resulting decimals then round the number :| this kind of sucks.